# how to version multiple tables with dexie 3.0, when users may jump from any previous version to the latest?

Tags: node.js, versioning, dexie

After studying the [Dexie documentation on versioning](https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Design#database-versioning), I am unclear about some aspects of versioning using Dexie 3.0.1.

Suppose I have `table1` and `table2` with only `id` as an index on each for version 1 of my db:

```
db.version(1).stores({table1: "++id", table2: "++id"});
```

For version 2 of my db, I add `shoeSize` as an index of `table1`:

```
db.version(2).stores({table1: "++id,shoeSize"});
```

For version 3 of my db, I add `dateOfBirth` as an index of `table2`.

```
db.version(3).stores({table2: "++id,dateOfBirth"});
```

If I understand correctly, for Dexie 3.0, my final code should only have the last change to `stores`:  `db.version(3).stores({table2: "++id,dateOfBirth"});`.  It will NOT have version 2:  `db.version(2).stores({table1: "++id,shoeSize"});`.

So, if a user installs version 1 of my app, then upgrades directly to version 3, how will his `table1` get updated to have the `shoeSize` index?  How should I handle versioning multiple tables with Dexie 3.0?

Comment: it should be just the index list i believe, this index list can just be skipped to the last version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the current documentation](https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Design#database-versioning):

> If a previous version is installed, Dexie will filter out the diff
> between each version and add/remove stores and indexes sequentially.

=> you specify all the version changes and Dexie will execute each necessary ones.
In your example, a user having a DB at v1 and downloading the v3 code, will have Dexie running both lines:

```
db.version(3).stores({table2: "++id,dateOfBirth"});
db.version(2).stores({table1: "++id,shoeSize"});
```